# How does implicit conversions between scala-java collections work? How is it possible that it is sufficient to import some package?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, scala-java-interop

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
val j: java.util.Map[String, String] = Map("a" -> "b")
print (j)
```

How does it work? In other words I am dying to know how import of some library (`JavaConversions` here) can help in making some conversions. After all, I didn't call any conversion function.
How does it work?

Comment: You can read about the implicit conversions [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-conversions.html) As the name suggests, these conversions are done implicitly... as opposed to explicitly where you would need to make a call. Those converters are defined generically, such that it defines how to convert a generic Scala `Map[A, B]` to Java `util.Map[A, B]` so whenever this conversion sees a concrete Scala Map in your code, it takes the liberty to convert to an instance of a Java Map

Comment: Does it mean that conversion is done runtime?

Comment: No, they are done at the compile time. You might be doing an arbitrary conversion such as from `Int -> String` so if you do something even more arbitrary like `5 + "hello"` the compile still needs to type check that and make sure you aren't imagining things that will make the program crash later

Comment: Just FYI: `JavaConversions` was deprecated as of 2.12.0 in favor of `JavaConverters` and it is unavailable in 2.13. `JavaConverters` has been deprecated as of 2.13.0 and has been split into various `scala.jdk.XxxConverters` libraries.

Comment: More FYI: Martin Odersky has been arguing [against implicit conversions](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/can-we-wean-scala-off-implicit-conversions/4388) but not everyone is convinced.

Comment: "Does it mean that conversion is done runtime?" Depends on what you mean by "done". They are inserted by the compiler at compile-time; but executed at runtime.

Comment: Do not use implicit conversions, as you have seen that are too black magic and can make your code hard to read.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Well, here implicit conversion is for introducing an extension method (`.asJava`).

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Ah, ok, now `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._` are for extension methods but previous `scala.collection.JavaConversions._` for actual implicit conversions.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I consider **extension methods** and **implicit conversions** two different things, that the first one is under the hood implemented using the second one is meaningless _(IMHO)_. A similar _(but obviously exaggerated and contrived)_ example would be saying that assembler code is difficult to understand and that **C** is closer to humans, and argue against saying that at the end **C** is compiled into assembly code. - Making clear my point in the previous comment was that **implicit conversions** _(as a language feature)_ are hard to understand and can make your code fragile.

Answer (score 3):

You can always see how implicits are resolved using `reify`

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify

println(reify{
  Map("a" -> "b").asJava
}.tree)
//CollectionConverters.MapHasAsJava(Predef.Map.apply(Predef.ArrowAssoc("a").$minus$greater("b"))).asJava
```

So with implicits brought by the import of `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._` the line

```
val j: java.util.Map[String, String] = Map("a" -> "b").asJava
```

is transformed into

```
val j: java.util.Map[String, String] =
  CollectionConverters.MapHasAsJava(Map("a" -> "b")).asJava
```

This rewriting (implicit resolution) occurs at compile time using static types, but methods `.MapHasAsJava(..)`, `.asJava` are called as always at runtime using dynamic dispatch.

Similarly, with former version of Scala

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

println(reify{
  val j: java.util.Map[String, String] = Map("a" -> "b")
}.tree)
//val j: Map[Predef.String, Predef.String] = JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap(Predef.Map.apply(Predef.ArrowAssoc("a").$minus$greater("b")));
```

means that the line

```
val j: java.util.Map[String, String] = Map("a" -> "b")
```

is transformed into

```
val j: java.util.Map[String, String] =
  JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap(Map("a" -> "b"))
```